# WSO2 Send Recovery Notification

Tags: authentication, wso2, soapui

In our current WSO2 setup, after a user performs a self creation, we place his account into a locked state, and send a confirmation email to the address specified during creation.  This email has a link which allows the user to verify his account.

For development purposes, we are attempting to get the workflow down using the `UserInformationRecoveryService` wsdl in SOAP UI.  The service which we seem to want is called `sendRecoveryNotification`.  Here is the signature of this service:

```
sendRecoveryNotification(String username, String key, String notificationType)
```

The `username` parameter is simply the username of the WSO2 user in question, which we have.  For the `notificationType` we have been using `email`, which presumably would trigger an email to be sent to the user.  The problem is with the `key` parameter.  It is not clear what value should be used as `key`, and all our guesses always lead to this error response:

> 18001 invalid confirmation code for user : tbiegeleisen@abc.com@tenant.com

We also noticed that several other services also expect a key, and it is not clear how to get this value.

Can someone shed light on the workflow for user recovery in WSO2?  It seems to be a Catch-22 with regard of requiring a token in order to generate a new token to be sent to a user.

Answer (score 1):

The [WSO2 documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Recover+with+Notification) clearly spells out the workflow for recovery with notification.  The `key` which needs to be used is the return value from a call to the `verifyUser()` SOAP web service.  This service itself expects a Captcha which normally would be sent from the UI.  Here is a code snippet showing how a recovery notification can be sent:

```
String cookies = client.login("admin@tenant.com@tenant.com", "admin");
UserInformationRecoveryUtil userInfoutil = new UserInformationRecoveryUtil(webserviceUrl, cookies);
CaptchaInfoBean captchaInfo = new CaptchaInfoBean();
captchaInfo.setImagePath(captchaPath);
captchaInfo.setSecretKey(captchaKey);
captchaInfo.setUserAnswer(captcha);
String username = emailId + "@" + tenantDomain;
String key = userInfoutil.verifyUser(username, captchaInfo);

// now pass the key based on the Captcha along with the type of recovery action
userInfoutil.sendRecoveryNotification(username, key, "accountUnLock");
```